# Fail to start openfire 3.10.0 with JDK1.8 and Mac Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: java, macos, openfire

I install openfire 3.10.0(latest version).

And my Mac's version is 10.10.3,my JDK is 1.8.

I don't know why I always fail to start openfire.

[image: fail to start openfire]

And I got some log content like below:

[image]

Comment: Any log files to show?

Answer (score 10):

@Zil Mike
At first I was like solving problems, But then, I still feel too much trouble.After trying, I find a new solution.

```
    step 1:remove jdk
    in Terminal
    sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
    rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
    rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
    rm -rf /Library/Java

    step 2:remove openfire
    in Terminal
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/openfire
    sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/Openfire.prefPane
    sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jivesoftware.openfire.plist
    sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/openfire.plist
    sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/Openfire.pkg

    step 3:reinstall jdk
    step 4:reinstall openfire
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man!! you saved my day.. (y).
Tried with my 10.10 yosemite os, it worked fine

Comment: I tried with yosemite, didnt worked, It worked in marvericks :S

Comment: Previously I had just updated my version with the Java updater but this didn't let openfire work for me, using the terminal commands to remove and reinstall worked great

Comment: Worked for me on Yosemite

Comment: I tried with all the given steps above in OS X El_Capitan but unfortunately it's not working for me. :(.

have any other solution here?

Comment: This worked dude.. Again mine is 10.10.3 yosemite os